# Hardcoding image links in php file in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am modifying footer.php file, and I would like to add some image from my gallery.
This is what I do:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/googleplay_button.png" />
```

The correct link appears on the webpage, but it is the link itself that is shown instead of an image.

Any help is much appreciated

After changing to `get_template_template_uri()`, here is the source code:

```
<img src="http://domain.com/promo/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/googleplay_button.png" height="43" width="140"/>
```

The problem is, that I am using a child theme which is called "divi-child". So that is what has to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use

```
get_template_directory_uri();
```

so your code will look like this

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/googleplay_button.png" alt="">
```

you can learn more [here:::](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

Comment: Is there some other information that is valuable that I can provide?

Comment: @Domas okay that is odd.. can you provide more info, do you get any console errors?

Comment: Also can just post more of you code, to be able to find what is really causing this error

Comment: I have updated my question with what is going to help you, i hope.

Comment: Ohh the images were in uploads folder, so the path was wrong. Still, thanks for help.